# How can we get the drawable subfolder name which is picked by android device

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to know which drawable sub-folder (hdpi,ldlpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,etc) is used by my application. I have one 10 inch tab which takes resources from xlarge-hdpi folder, but when I tried "Display metrics" it provides 240 dpi i.e "hdpi". I want to know which drawable sub-folder is used by the application in different phones ?
I tried by using Display Metrics but couldn't find the correct drawable folder 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics

Comment: Use `Configuration`. You can get this by calling `getResources().getConfiguration()` on your `Activity`.

Comment: Check  [this](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp)

Comment: If this is only for "debugging" you can try adding a values-xxxx with a `dimension.xml` which has different values (1 in hdpi, 2 in ldpi, etc` so you can print at runtime which one is being picked. I mean, it's a hack, but it takes 2 minutes to do it, and it may answer the question faster than trying to understand the resources configuration. :)